# Agregando Bootstrap, se muestra el código tal cual en lugar de ser renderizarse dos botones

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap

Querría tener un buscador, paginado y encima con formato bootstrap.

El caso es que funciona bien, pero cuando le añado la parte de bootstrap, me muestra la tabla pero justo donde van los botones me muestra en el siguiente código (y no muestra los botones):

```html
<div class="d-flex gap-2 justify-content-center py-5">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-rounded" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark">Editar</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-rounded" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark">Eliminar</button>
</div>
```

Os dejo el código casi completo menos la conexión a la sql.

¿Qué puede estar pasando?

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Inventari ICS</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.0/bootstrap-table.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//rawgit.com/vitalets/x-editable/master/dist/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<!-- partial -->
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.0/bootstrap-table.js'></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/editable/bootstrap-table-editable.js'></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.js'></script>
<script src='//rawgit.com/hhurz/tableExport.jquery.plugin/master/tableExport.js'></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/examples/buttons/">

</head>
<body>
<div class="row table-responsive">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h2>Inv</h2></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
     

        <?php
    
            
             $co1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM alumnos WHERE es='MI'");
             $row=mysqli_fetch_array($co1);
             $res1= $row['COUNT(*)'];
             
             $co2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM alumnos WHERE es='PE'");
             $row=mysqli_fetch_array($co2);
             $res2= $row['COUNT(*)'];
             
             $co3 = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM alumnos WHERE es='BA'");
             $row=mysqli_fetch_array($co3);
             $res3= $row['COUNT(*)'];
             
             $co4 = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM alumnos WHERE es='MIGRI'");
             $row=mysqli_fetch_array($co4);
             $res4= $row['COUNT(*)'];           
             
             $co5 = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM alumnos WHERE op='1'");
             $row=mysqli_fetch_array($co5);
             $res5= $row['COUNT(*)'];       
             
             $co6 = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM alumnos WHERE call='1'");
             $row=mysqli_fetch_array($co6);
             $res6= $row['COUNT(*)'];       
             
             $co7 = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM alumnos WHERE enq='1'");
             $row=mysqli_fetch_array($co7);
             $res7= $row['COUNT(*)'];   
    echo '<div align="center">
         <table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
         
            <tr>
                <td><div align="center">Mi:</div></td>
                <td><div align="center">Mig:</div></td>
                <td><div align="center">Cep:</div></td>
                <td><div align="center">Ceb:</div></td>
                <td><div align="center">Op Automàtiques:</div></td>
                <td><div align="center">Call:</div></td>
                <td><div align="center">En:</div></td>              
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div align="center"><h2>'.$res1.'</h2></div></td>
                <td><div align="center"><h2>'.$res4.'</h2></div></td>
                <td><div align="center"><h2>'.$res2.'</h2></div></td>
                <td><div align="center"><h2>'.$res3.'</h2></div></td>
                <td><div align="center"><h2>'.$res5.'</h2></div></td>
                <td><div align="center"><h2>'.$res6.'</h2></div></td>
                <td><div align="center"><h2>'.$res7.'</h2></div></td>               
                
            </tr>                   
                
               </table></div>'
         ?>


                  <table   
                        id="table"
                        data-toggle="table"
                        data-height="600"
                        data-search="true"
                        data-regex-search="true"
                        data-pagination="true"
                        data-url="json/data1.json">
                        
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        
                        <th data-field="id">ID</th>
                        <th data-field="ger">Ger</th>
                        <th data-field="cod" >Codi</th>
                        <!-- <th data-field="al">Al</th>-->
                        <th data-field="ser">Ser</th>
                        <th data-field="seu">Seu</th>
                        <!-- <th data-field="tip" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Tip</th>-->
                        <!-- <th data-field="municipi" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Mu</th>-->
                        <th data-field="in">iN</th>
                        <!--<th data-field="ag" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Ag</th>-->
                        <!-- <th data-field="siv" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">SIV</th>-->
                        <!-- <th data-field="extav" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Ext. Av.</th>-->
                        <!-- <th data-field="extbas" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Ext. Bas.</th>-->
                        <!-- <th data-field="exttotal" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Tot.</th>-->
                        <!--<th data-field="onenet" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">On</th>-->
                        <!--<th data-field="ext" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Ext. On</th>-->
                        <!--<th data-field="web" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Web</th>-->
                        <!--<th data-field="extweb" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Ext, Web.</th>-->
                        <!--<th data-field="opauto" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Operadora</th>-->
                        <!--<th data-field="callback" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Callback</th>-->
                        <!--<th data-field="enq" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Enq</th>-->
                        <th data-field="es">Es</th>
                        <!--<th data-field="fase" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Fase</th>-->
                        <th data-field="obs">Obs</th>
                        <th>Acc</th>
     
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                    <tbody>
                        <?php 
                        while($row1 = $resulta->fetch_array()){
                            //while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($resulta)){ 
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?=$row1[0]?></td>
                            <td><?=$row1[1]?></td>
                            <td><?=$row1[2] ?></td>
                            <td><?=$row1[4]?></td>
                            <td><?=$row1[5]?></td>
                            <td><?=$row1[8]?></td>           
                            <td><?=$row1[21]?></td>         
                            <td><?=$row1[23]?></td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="d-flex gap-2 justify-content-center py-5">
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-rounded" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark">Editar</button>
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-rounded" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark">Eliminar</button>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                       </tr> 
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>

        </div>
      </div>     
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Nyigu, bienvenido, no creo que sea la razón de tu problema, pero el último **</div>** estaría sobrando...

Comment: No imprimas código HTML con PHP. Sepáralos !!!

Comment: Pero entonces el while como lo pongo? El otro código php de arriba si lo puedo mover sin problema, pero como lo hago con el while?

Comment: Si en la edición no se refleja el problema real que estás teniendo en el título, edita de nuevo la pregunta. Por cierto, haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: El problema real es tal cual describo en mi primera entrada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se debe a la versión que estas usando.

Si usas la versión `1.10.0` de `Bootstrap Table`, ves el contenido de los `<td>` como texto.

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.0/bootstrap-table.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//rawgit.com/vitalets/x-editable/master/dist/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<!-- partial -->
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.0/bootstrap-table.js'></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/editable/bootstrap-table-editable.js'></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.js'></script>
<script src='//rawgit.com/hhurz/tableExport.jquery.plugin/master/tableExport.js'></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.js'></script>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/examples/buttons/">
<div class="row table-responsive">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h2>Inv</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">

    <table id="table" data-toggle="table" data-height="600" data-search="true" data-regex-search="true" data-pagination="true">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-field="id">ID</th>
          <th data-field="ger">Ger</th>
          <th data-field="cod">Codi</th>
          <th data-field="ser">Ser</th>
          <th data-field="seu">Seu</th>
          <th data-field="in">iN</th>
          <th data-field="es">Es</th>
          <th data-field="obs">Obs</th>
          <th>Acc</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <?=$row1[0]?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?=$row1[1]?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?=$row1[2] ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?=$row1[4]?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?=$row1[5]?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?=$row1[8]?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?=$row1[21]?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?=$row1[23]?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="d-flex gap-2 justify-content-center py-5">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-rounded" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark">Editar</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-rounded" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark">Eliminar</button>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

En cambio, si usas la version `1.22.0` de `Bootstrap Table`, vas a ver el contenido de los `<td>` como HTML.

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.22.0/bootstrap-table.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//rawgit.com/vitalets/x-editable/master/dist/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<!-- partial -->
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.22.0/bootstrap-table.js'></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.22.0/extensions/editable/bootstrap-table-editable.js'></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.22.0/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.js'></script>
<script src='//rawgit.com/hhurz/tableExport.jquery.plugin/master/tableExport.js'></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.22.0/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.js'></script>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/examples/buttons/">
<div class="row table-responsive">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h2>Inv</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">

    <table id="table" data-toggle="table" data-height="600" data-search="true" data-regex-search="true" data-pagination="true">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-field="id">ID</th>
          <th data-field="ger">Ger</th>
          <th data-field="cod">Codi</th>
          <th data-field="ser">Ser</th>
          <th data-field="seu">Seu</th>
          <th data-field="in">iN</th>
          <th data-field="es">Es</th>
          <th data-field="obs">Obs</th>
          <th>Acc</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <?=$row1[0]?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?=$row1[1]?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?=$row1[2] ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?=$row1[4]?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?=$row1[5]?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?=$row1[8]?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?=$row1[21]?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?=$row1[23]?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="d-flex gap-2 justify-content-center py-5">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-rounded" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark">Editar</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-rounded" data-mdb-ripple-color="dark">Eliminar</button>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Si señor! Era las versiones. No sabía que tenía tanta diferencia. Muchas gracias!!!!